# estimates on an improper integral associated with normal distributuion

Tags: integration, estimation, gaussian-integral

Show that $\int_{x}^{\infty}e^{-\frac{t^2}{2}}dt\geq e^{-\frac{t^2}{2}}(\frac{1}{x}-\frac{1}{x^3}) $ for all positive $x$

Does it require the mean value theorem, or the Taylor series expansion? It is easy to show that the above inequality is reversed if the $x^{-3}$ term is dropped, i.e. 
$$\int_{x}^{\infty}e^{-\frac{t^2}{2}}dt\leq e^{-\frac{t^2}{2}}\frac{1}{x} $$ for all positive $x$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hint: Start by using integration by parts, $u=\frac{1}{t}$ and $dv=te^{-t^2/2}\,dt$. After you do the calculation, how to continue may be clear.

Comment: Thanks! Now I have known the trick of constructing the term "$te^{-t^2/2}$".

Comment: You are welcome. It is then easiest to use the trick twice, though there are other ways. Note there is a little typo in the post, we want in the first line $e^{-x^2/2}(1/x-1/x^3)$.